# Conditional Probability of independent performances of the experiment

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

A random experiment has three possible outcomes A, B and C, with probabilities $p_A, p_B$ and $p_C$
What is the probability that, in independent performances of the experiment, A will occur before B?

Let an event D: A occurs before B

$ P(D) = _ + __ + __^2 + ⋯ = \frac{_}{1-p_c}$

I'm not able to get this solution. Why are there only events like $AC^n$, shouldn't it be like $A^mC^n$ where m and n denote the number of times event A or C is happening before B. Therefore shouldn't the sum should include terms like $p_a^mp_c^n$ ?

Comment: I understand it as follows: the first term in the sum $p_A$ corresponds to the case where event A happens first (so obviously A is before B and nothing left to do). The second term is the case where first C happens then A happens (again A before B and we are finished). The third term is two times C happening first then A... and so on. Theres no $A^m$ there because A only has to happen ONCE before B.

Comment: I get it, but from where in the question are you getting that "A only has to happen ONCE before B" @Burgulence

Comment: As soon as A happens before B, the rest of the chain of events is not relevant anymore so in a sense you can sum over all possible outcomes of future events in a specific chain. But the sum over all possible future outcomes is 1 and thus can be omitted in the formula. E.g. take the case where A happens first. Then whatever happens in the future in this chain of events does not matter anymore because A is already before B

Comment: $p_A = p_A *(\text{sum over all future events})$ but $\text{"sum over all future events"} = 1$. Your $A^m C^n$ terms are implicitly hidden in the "sum over all future events".

Comment: Ohkay, i got it. Thanks for making it clear.